# Unary and Binary Operations in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I've been working through my textbook on the chapter concerning assembly language and have come to a practice problem that I do not understand (the section on unary and binary operations is quite minimal so I'm pretty lost).

Here are two instructions from the practice problem. I am supposed to give the destination and value of each instruction:

> addq %rcx, (%rax)
>
> imulq $16 , (%rax, %rdx, 8)

Where %rax's value is 0x100, %rdx's value is 0x3 and %rcx's value is 0x1.

Can anyone explain in detail how to solve both instructions? I have the answer in the back of the book but there's no real explanation to go along with it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't add unrelated tags!

Comment: Sorry, my class is centered around the C programming language (and so is the textbook) which is why I included it.

Comment: But your question is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to know
1) how effective addresses work
2) how to use the instruction set reference to figure out what instructions do

In short, `disp(%base, %index, scale)` is a memory reference to address `%base + %index * scale + disp`. All parts except one are optional. `scale` can be `1`, `2`, `4` or `8`.

Now, if you look up `add` in the manual, you can see it just adds the first operand to the second so that adds `1` (value of `%rcx`) to the qword in memory at address `0x100` (value of `%rax`).

The second instruction is invalid, there is no such form of `imul`. Maybe you forgot to copy another operand?

Even though it does not exist, we can guess what the author wanted it to mean, namely, to multiply the second operand by the first. As such, this would multiply the qword in memory at address `0x100 + 3 * 8 = 0x118` by `16`.

Comment: What I'm confused about is that for 1: They have the destination as 0x100 and the value as 0x100. I thought that addq &rcx, (%rax) would turn into (%rax) + %rcx => 0x100 + 0x1 => 0x101. 


For number 2: they have the destination to be 0x118 and the value to be 0x110

Comment: It does **not** add the `1` to the `0x100`. It adds the `1` to the qword in memory at address `0x100`. Now if they have told you that memory content at that address is also `0x100`, then indeed the result could be `0x101`. For the second instruction, it doesn't make sense to talk about destination and value because that instruction does not exist. Verify you copied it correctly.

Comment: I verified that I copied it correctly. How it appears in my original post is how it is written in the book. It is similar to the problem on page 127 (107 page number- 127 page of the document) of the earlier version of my textbook [earlier version link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.138.4401&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Well, that book is broken. That instruction does not exist. It's not in the reference manual and the assembler doesn't accept it either. By the way, the contents of memory are given on the preceding page. You need to use that for the first instruction, to know the resulting value.

Comment: Thanks for the help- I might bring up #2 with my professor to see what he says.

Comment: Please edit the additional information you have been given about the contents of memory into your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is from Practice Problem 3.8 in CS:APP 3/e (global edition)

```
Address    Value
0x100      0XFF
0x118      0x11

Register   Value
%rax       0x100
%rcx       0x1
%rdx       0x3
```

> addq %rcx,(%rax)

For this question, you take the qword at %rax (0XFF) and add %rcx to it, so 0XFF + 0x1 = 0x100. Note the brackets around (%rax) which points to the contents held in memory (0XFF) not it's address (0x100).

> imulq $16,(%rax, %rdx, 8)

As noted by jester, the right-hand side (%rax + (%rdx * 8)) which is 0x118. The value stored at that address is 0x11. imulq now multiplies 0x11 * 0x10 (note, 16 converted to hex is 0x10) and answer 0x110.